# Rspec have_content throwing error even when the content is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I am using cucumber along with capybara, rspec helpers for wring test cases.

When I use have_content for verifying a text is present in a particular page, it is throwing error even if the content is present in the page.

My Feature file is

```
When I visit "/news"
Then I should not see a page with following content
  | content                                                                          |
  | .*Confirm your email address now.* |
```

The step definition file is

```
Then /^I should see a page with following content$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    page.should have_content(hash[:content])
  end
end
```

The error which I am getting is

> RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected to find text
>   ".*Confirm your email address now.*" in "The North FaceBanana
>   RepublicLevi'sadidasTrue ReligionJ. CrewJordanPolo by Ralph
>   LaurenKids' BrandsGAPCarter'sNikeChildren's PlaceGymboreeOshKosh
>   B'goshConverseRalph LaurenJusticeOld NavyPeople Also
>   SearchedVictoria’s SecretChristian LouboutinGoyardForever
>   21AsosPartiesHow it worksSell on PoshmarkNewsAllCommentsOffersWant to
>   sell your stuff? Download Poshmark on your mobile device!Confirm your
>   email address now to make sure you receive important order and account
>   information."

And the text which I am looking for is present in the page too.

Please help me if I am wrong at somewhere..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the mistake that I have done.

have_content will take a regular expression but for that you need to pass it a regular expression - page.should have_content(/.*blah.*/). If you pass it a string it does a substring match on the relevant elements content, unless you pass the exact option which would then make it do an exact match element.should have_content('blah', exact: true)

Changing the feature file

```
When I visit "/news"
Then I should not see a page with following content
  | content                                                                          |
  | Confirm your email address now|
```

instead of

```
When I visit "/news"
Then I should not see a page with following content
  | content                                                                          |
  | .*Confirm your email address now.* |
```

rectifies the error.

Comment: Note: `have_content` will take a regular expression but for that you need to pass it a regular expression -  `page.should have_content(/.*blah.*/)`.  If you pass it a string it does a substring match on the relevant elements content, unless you pass the `exact` option which would then make it do an exact match `element.should have_content('blah', exact: true)`

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks a lot and I have added your note in the answer